# Goggle map API - to read "my current location" on Google map on mobile devices

Tags: api

I am writing a web application which will be used on web browser on mobile phones (aspx app hosted on the Azure App Services). My question is: On any mobile devices, especially iPhone, Android, etc. there is a map icon, I believed it's Google map, that I can get "my current address" by holding on the little blue dot then Google map would give me a pop-up with a physical address displayed - more detail here: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/2839911?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS. Can I use the Google API, or some type of Google service(s), to somehow do the exact same from my web app,  programmatically to capture that "my current location" just like Google map is doing? Thank you in advance.